# Помогите дописать Shell-скрипт для подключения по RDS Shadow

Tags: windows, сервер, shell, rdp, remote

помогите пожалуйста допилить скрипт для подключения по RDS Shadow в домене. Развернут домен, Active Directory.
Есть скрипт для подключения (простой батник)

```
@echo off
set /P rcomp="Vvedite nazvanie PC ili IP address "
query session /server:%rcomp%
set /P rid="Vvedite ID sessii: "
start mstsc /shadow:%rid% /v:%rcomp% /control
```

3 строка выводит таблицу активных сеансов выбранного ПК,
и в этой таблице есть столбец: Статус и ID,
и вот вопрос, можно ли сделать логику, чтобы он находил статус "Active"
и брал ID из строки напротив этого столбца Active,
и подставлял этот ID уже в самую нижнюю строку.

Так сказать автоматизировать процесс удаленного подключения к пользователю просто вводом IP адреса

Comment: проще написать скрипт на любом языке и вызвать его, передав ему выхлоп query session, чтобы он извлёк нужный ID

Comment: Всего две команды батника для поиска. Запомнить строку с (последним) активным пользователем, затем извлечь с нужной позиции номер сессии: `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%i IN ('QUSER /SERVER:%rcomp% ^| FIND "Активно"') DO SET "I=%%i"` `SET rid=%I:~42,2%`